# How to connect web server using own domain in apache2 for django frame work

Tags: python, django, apache, webserver

I'm trying to connect my project to server using **`apache2`**.

This is my code in `domainname.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/<project>/<project>/wsgi.py

   ServerName <domainname.com>
   Alias /static /var/www/<project>/static/

   <Directory /var/www/<project>/>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, I am not able to connecting to server. Someone please have a look into this.

Comment: Why have you added those quotes? You should remove them.

Comment: i didn't add to my. i added here (in stack overflow), for formatting

Comment: Hi can you look at this answer it will help you [django project run through apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840539/7261317)

Comment: I don't understand why, they just make it harder to read. I've removed them.

Comment: Thanks and Sorry i don't how to formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace *:80 with your IP-address. also check the wsgi script . after restarting apache2 see the log file (access.log and error.log)

```
<VirtualHost 132.123.123.2 >
    ....
    WSGIDaemonProcess yourdomain.com 
    WSGIProcessGroup yourdomain.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yourdomain.com/index.wsgi
    ....
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and wsgi script something like this :

```
import os
import sys
import site

site.addsitedir('/user/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/home/path/to/project')
sys.path.append('/home/path/to/project/main_app')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'main_app.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```