# Deploy Django with mod_wsgi on special port number

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have run Django 1.11.4 with mod_wsgi and Apache2.4 with a virtualenv Python3.4 environment on Centos VPS. After configuring `mod_wsgi` in virtual hostrunnig and running `apachectl restart` I get:

> (98)Address already in use: make_sock: unable to listen for
>   connections on address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: make_sock:
>   unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:80

**Port 80 is in use.**

**This is my virtualHost:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias 91.132.233.168
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html

    Alias /memit /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/myproject

    <Directory /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess memit python-path=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/memit:/opt/rh/httpd24/root/va$
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

**My questions: How can I change Django port to special port?**

Comment: can you look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840539/7261317

Comment: Surely you should investigate what is on port 80, rather than trying to move your website to a non-standard port. Have you got another installation of Apache? Or nginx maybe?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have find another Apache on server that it is using port 80. on my server Tomcat 8 is installed. I think this Apache is using by Tomcat and I have stopped and kill this Apache port! My problem is solved after kill this port! But Tomcat 8 is still running and alive! Why?!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know that Changing Django port is non-standard. But I wanna to find a way to run Django on special port on mod_wsgi. Is there any way?

Comment: When using Tomcat, it itself wouldn't be listening on port 80. The separate Apache would have been accepts requests on port 80 and then proxying requests to the separate Tomcat process. So stopping that Apache doesn't stop Tomcat as it was started separately.

Comment: As using a different port, you need to tell Apache to listen on the different port using the ``Listen`` directive. Then change the port number in ``<VirtualHost *:80>``. You may need to define ``ServerName`` properly for the ``VirtualHost`` as well though.

Comment: What you may be better off doing is using ``mod_wsgi-express``. It uses a separate port as a default. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi