# Django on Apache redirects incorrect

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am currently hosting my Django site on an Apache server. The Django site works fine when hosting it locally, but when I host it from the server any time you attempt to navigate to a different part of the site there's an error. As it stands you can get to the home page by navigating to `example.com/djproj` this pulls up the login screen as it should. When you enter your credentials and hit the submit button it takes you to `example.com` which is not supported, however if you manually navigate back to `example.com/djproj` it takes you to the home screen and you're logged in, clicking any of the buttons gives you a similar error. Notably, if you attempt to go to a supported url (one in the urls file) by directly typing it in, ie `example.com/djproj/precheck/` you get a 404 stating the request URL is `example.com//precheck/`.

I will try to provide the scripts I think applicable, but if I'm missing something I'll be happy to provide.

The file structure looks like `/var/www/html/djproj/cif` where `cif` holds all the typical django files such as `manage.py` and the associated application folders.

**wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = 'var/www/djproj/grip/cif'

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "grip.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from precheck import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^precheck/', include('precheck.urls')),
    url(r'^[/]?$', views.upload, name = 'home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**httpd.conf** (The applicable portions)

```
WSGIScriptAlias /djproj/ /var/www/html/djproj/cif/grip/wsgi.py process-group=16$
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/djproj/

<Directory /var/www/html/djproj/cif/grip>
   <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

**EDIT: Trying suggestions in comments.**

I changed the urls to the following:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^djproj/accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^djproj/*precheck/', include('precheck.urls')),
    url(r'^djproj[/]?$', views.upload, name = 'home'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I attempt to navigate to `example.com/djproj` it says it `Page not found at /` it seems when Apache passes back the url it's dropping `example.com/djproj`. Similarly if I try `example.com/djproj/precheck/` I get a 404 with a request url of `example.com//precheck/` and it says `The current path, /precheck/, didn't match any of these.` 'these' being the urls listed in urlpatterns above.

EDIT (Showing how URLs are coded):

**upload.html**

```
<form method = "POST" action="{% url 'precheck:upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-row">
        {{field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class ="help-text">{{ field.help_text }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <br />
    <button type="button" id="uploadButton" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off">Upload</button>

</form>
```

Note the use of `{% url 'precheck:upload'}` Here's where it points to in `prechecks.urls`:

**urls.py - prechecks**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'precheck'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^success/', views.successful_upload, name = 'successful_upload'),
    url(r'^failed_upload/', views.failed_upload, name = 'failed_upload'),
    url(r'^run_precheck/', views.run_precheck, name = 'run_precheck'),
    url(r'^running_checks/', views.run_selected_checks, name = 'run_selected_checks'),
    url(r'^checks_successful/', views.checks_successful, name = 'checks_successful'),
    url(r'^checks_failed/', views.checks_failed, name = 'checks_failed'),
    url(r'^$', views.upload, name = 'upload'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            request.session['jobID'] = request.POST['jobID']
            #job = Job.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id).filter(jobID = request.POST['jobID']).latest()
            # initialize(job)
            return render(request,'precheck/run_precheck.html')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'precheck/upload.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: Sounds like you aren't using ``url()`` in templates and code to properly construct the full absolute URL for links. This has to be used so that the mount point for the Django application is included in the URL. Otherwise you will be missing the ``/djproj`` prefix. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton looking at the docs you linked and playing around with this I don't think this is the issue.
See edit above for reasoning.

Comment: Your routes in url patterns shouldn't have ``djproj/`` at the front. That is dropped in the URL which is passed for pattern matching. In other words, the patterns should not include any specific mount point the WSGI server is told to use. Also, you home page pattern should be ``r'^$'``, not ``r'^[/]?$'``. Having the slash in the latter likely screwed up trailing slash redirection. It would also be more usual to use ``WSGIScriptAlias /djproj``. That is no trailing slash in mod_wsgi directive for mount point.

Comment: Also use ``path = '/var/www/djproj/grip/cif'`` and not ``path = 'var/www/djproj/grip/cif'``. Define it as an absolute path, not relative as not guaranteed what working directory will be.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton pretty much all of the things you commented on (with the exception of the path change) were how things were to begin with. Adding the djproj/ to the url patterns was an attempt to get the links to reverse correctly. As stated if I click a button it does not append the `/djproj` to `example.com` as I need it to.

Comment: Are you using ``url()`` in your code/templates or not? Or are you hardwiring the URL path without using any helper to construct the full URL? Show an example of how you code is creating the link behind the button.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I am using url in the templates. I added examples above.

Comment: Are you setting ``FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`` in Django settings? You do not want to be doing that. If you do it will muck things up.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton No, I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try this post

[django apache configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840539/7261317)

also refer the orginal document

[Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)